# Jmeter: multi user login with session

Tags: jmeter

i am new to jmeter and i am trying to login with 3 different users using the CSV config, but the problem is when i login with second user, the first user gets logged out.
Similarly logging in with third user logs out the second user. How to handle it using jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

I think on any website at a time only one user can logon as the session allows only one.
So if jMeter is trying to logging in by the second user it must be logout the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add cookie manager
2) Instead of logging all three users in one scenario make looped scenario where first user logs in during the first session, the second one in the second session and so on.

Or you could make three different threads and all the users would connect at the same time with different sessions. But it is more heavy resource-wise.